# Post On Facebook on behalf of user: Invalid OAuth access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I am developing an Laravel App.I want to post on facebook on behalf of logged in user via my app.I have logged in my site via facebook/default  authentication system.I have gotten this error:

```
Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token.
```

I have added this route:

```
Route::get('post/facebook','ProjectController@post');
```

In my post method:

```
{  
   $user=Auth::user()->facebook_id;


    return view('Facebook.post',compact('user'));

}
```

Then In my View:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '*********',
  'app_secret' => '*************',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);





$linkData = [

  'message' => 'User provided message',
  ];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/'. $user .'/feed', $linkData, '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```